# Datetime and Stfrtime

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

I'm making a calculator which tells you how many days there is between today and the given date. The dates is imported from a file and is written in format yyyy/mm/dd and dd/mm/yyyy.

I have two problems:

1: The format which the dates are written in varies. A few of the dates is written in reverse. How do I reverse them? I get `ValueError: day is out of range for month.`

2: When I try to subtract "today" with the "dates" I get the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'` and when I add "int" I get `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2015, 10, 23'`

Any advice? :)

```
for line in response:
 line = (line.decode(encoding).strip())
 year, month, day = line.split('/')

 today = date.today().strftime("%Y, %m, %d")
 dates = datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day)).strftime("%Y, %m, %d")

 print(int(today)-int(dates))
```

Comment: Just subtract one datetime object from another datetime object. Rather than converting it to string or int.

Answer (score 1):

Your second problem is caused by calling strftime too early. date objects can be evaluated to each other, but strings cannot. ie

```
today = date.today()
dates = date(int(year), int(month), int(day))

print((today-dates).days)
```

also, you should use date objects for both.

You're second problem can be fixed with some simple error checking like

```
if year < day:
  switch(year,day) #pseudo code
```

or something more verbose than that but you get the idea.

EDIT:
I forgot that comparisons return a timedelta object. these objects only hold days and smaller time sequences (hours, mins, seconds etc)

Comment: AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'strftime' on print ((today-dates).strftime('%Y,%m,%d'))

Answer (score 1):

No need to convert into integer if you have two date objects, you can just subtract one from the other and query the resulting [`timedelta` object](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) for the number of days:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> a = date(2011,11,24)
>>> b = date(2011,11,17)
>>> a-b
datetime.timedelta(7)
>>> (a-b).days
7
```

And it works with datetimes too — I think it rounds down to the nearest day:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a = datetime(2011,11,24,0,0,0)
>>> b = datetime(2011,11,17,23,59,59)
>>> a-b
datetime.timedelta(6, 1)
>>> (a-b).days
6
```

Comment: I dont know what the dates are. And when I use "a = datetime(date.today)" I get "TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.date)". When i try "a = datetime(int(date.today))" I get "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.date'"